# How can I add shadow on piechart in recharts?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, recharts

I want to add shadow on piechart. I am using recharts library.

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if you have any solutions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a drop shadow filter on the `Cell` component(s) to add this effect.  I just passed the values in via the `style` prop, but you can do whatever works best for you.

[image]

```
    <PieChart width={800} height={400}>
      <Pie
        data={data}
        cx={120}
        cy={200}
        innerRadius={70}
        outerRadius={80}
        fill="#8884d8"
        dataKey="value"
      >
        {data.map((entry, index) => (
          <Cell
            key={`cell-${index}`}
            fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}
            style={{
              filter: `drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px ${COLORS[index % COLORS.length]}`
            }}
            stroke="0"
          />
        ))}
      </Pie>
    </PieChart>
```

Working Example CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pie-chart-with-drop-shadow-fxe8x?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. You saved my day.

Comment: @MidasDev You're welcome -- glad I could help!